# CodeIgniter not working with subfolders

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have my codeigniter code in web root. The mod_rewrite is enabled.. I checked through phpinfo.php. Now the code structure is something like this

```
  controllers/home.php(default controller)
  controllers/products.php (not listed in routes.php under config)
  and then a subfolder
  controllers/members/login.php
```

The urls I am trying are

```
 domain_name/ ---------> works
```

> (Note: this is where my echo base_url is pointing me to I guess
>   because $config['index.php'] = '', But even setting it to index.php is
>   not pointing me to the working index.php url)

```
  domain_name/products ------> doesn't work
    domain_name/index.php/products ------> works
    similarly 
    domain_name/members ----->doesn't work
    domain_name/index.php/members --->work
```

Because this thing is working with index.php I am guessing the routes.php is working fine. But some how echo $base_url is pointing me to these without index.php urls.

I have tried the .htacess file which is in my webroot that is /var/www/
   The version for codeigniter is 2.1.3

Please help. I want this to work with or without index.php and if you can explain what i am missing please give me explaination.

Answer (score 1):

In General Codeigniter tends to explicity hide index.php when call the its main root but when your trying to access its subfolders directly in the url .. index.php is required.In order to do that so you must include an .htaccess inside your ci filesystem that will accept the use of  domain/product or domain/index.php/product

So try to include this .htacess and change its rewrite base into your ci folder name

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cifolder

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```